# How can I set android permission in framework on runtime..

Tags: android, permissions, sendmessage

I made a class for sending special sms.. not in app. but in telephony framework..
there is a error that saying permission SEND_SMS..

How can I set SEND_SMS permission..?
I tried below..

```
if (mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   Log.d(TAG, "young.cha : Can't get PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED~~!! -____-;;; ");
   mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(
      android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, 
      "Requires SEND_SMS permission~~!!");
   Log.d(TAG, "young.cha : enforceCallingOrSelfPermission~~~~!! SEND_SMS~~~!");
}

else {
   Log.d(TAG, "young.cha : OK OK OK get PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED~~!! -____-;;; ");
}
```

enforceCallingOrSelfPermission and checkCallingOrSelfPermission are not working.. 
what did I wrong..? or What kind of methods will be effectable..?

help me again~~ plz~~

It's been 5 hours to solve this things... -_-;

Comment: do you have an exception? if so, could you post the logcat?

Comment: This depends on your implementation. Specifically  you should not being doing this, if anything you should move your code into a System Application to do what you're trying to do. Without an understanding of WHAT a framework is, you can not do this correctly. Work WITH the framework not against it, a framework is not an Application and should not be treated as such. Define your rules with respect to the framework, not against it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should set the `SEND_SMS` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

You cannot set permissions in runtime, they have to be accepted by the user before installing the app.

Comment: In the domain of the framework, this does not necessarily apply. Framework domain is different from app domain.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What exactly do you mean by "Framework domain"?